# get foreground from a video opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

i have a python code which treats the first frame of a video as background and using this first frame,absdiff is calculated on all the other remaining frames to get the foreground.But the background also overlaps on the foreground moving object!How do i get just the foreground moving object??

[image: first frame]

[image: another frame]

[image: detected foreground]

Comment: Did you consider any of the background subtractors such as `BackgroundBubtractorMOG2` or `BackgroundBubtractorKNN`?

Comment: yes,but i was not getting proper output with mog2 or knn, a lot of noise came with those algorithms